# Roman pagination up to the beginning of the chapter

Tags: page-numbering, roman-numerals

How do I get all pages numbered in Roman numerals before the beginning of the first chapter (with the exception of the title page)? The PDF program should be able to recognize which pages are numbered in Roman and which are in Arabic.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\title{abc}
\subtitle{def}
\author{ghi}
\date{mno}

\begin{document}

\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{pqr}\setcounter{page}{1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it as `\roman` (more common than `\Roman`) and then change it again to `\arabic` using `\pagenumber{arabic}`. Issuing the appropriate `\clearpage`s will help with the correct numbering.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\title{abc}
\subtitle{def}
\author{ghi}
\date{mno}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}

\maketitle

\clearpage

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}% Reset page numbering and style
\chapter{pqr}

\end{document}
```

The title is set without a page number by default, but still counts as a page.

Comment: What is the difference between `\cleardoublepage` and `\clearpage` in this context?

Comment: @Schubladenzieher: In general, some document classes forces a recto (right-hand) page for major document divisions (like `\part` and/or `\chapter`). `\cleardoublepage` will ensure that you're on that recto/right-hand page before setting the sectional unit. If the class doesn't have this restriction, `\cleardoublepage` defaults to `\clearpage`.

Comment: If I added `\addchap` before the table of contents (for example because of an acknowledgement), would I have to change `\clearpage` to `\cleardoublepage`?

Comment: Why not `\pagenumbering{roman}`?

Comment: How would this MWE look like? @egreg

Comment: @Schubladenzieher: True, you can use `\pagenumerbering{roman}` instead of `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}` in the preamble. It has the same effect (since resetting the page number here is superfluous, but harmless).

Comment: Which of the two possibilities would be the more elegant and actually correct way? @Werner

Comment: @Schubladenzieher: `\pagenumbering{roman}` has more contextual value, but it doesn't just change the numbering style; it also resets the page number. If you know what it's doing, using `\pagenumbering{roman}` for the context. If you're just changing the display mid-document and don't need the page numbers reset, use `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}`.

Comment: @Werner If I use `\pagenumbering{roman}`, do I still need `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage`?

Comment: @Schubladenzieher: Yes. `\pagenumbering{<style>}` does `\setcounter{page}{1}\renewcommand{\thepage}{\<style>{page}}` (at a lower level; see [`ltxpageno.dtx`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/ltpageno.dtx)) and that's it. It doesn't have anything to do with `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `scrreprt` with `scrbook` that provides page numbering in the desired fashion.

The only difference between the two classes is that `scrreprt` uses `oneside` by default.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\title{abc}
\subtitle{def}
\author{ghi}
\date{mno}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{pqr}

\end{document}
```

No `\cleardoublepage` necessary.

Comment: Why are there blank pages between title and table of contents and between table of contents and first chapter when I leave out `\oneside`? Wouldn't that be the right way to write a `scrbook`?

Comment: @Schubladenzieher The default for `scrbook` is `twoside`, so chapters start on odd numbered pages.

Comment: I am still a little confused about the difference between `\cleardoublepage` and `\clearpage` in `scrreprt`. If `scrreprt` has `oneside` as default, does that mean `\clearpage` would be enough? Or should I always use `\cleardoublepage` with such document classes?

Comment: @Schubladenzieher Under `oneside`, `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage` are equivalent.